# snowflake substring method is not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I tried substring method but it is not working and giving me this error.

```
create or replace procedure
dsa ()
returns varchar
language javascript
$$
var b="{asdfasdf}"
var c=b.substring(1);
return c;
 $$;
 call dsa();
```

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 5 at position 0 unexpected '$$ var b="{asdfasdf}" var c=b.substring(1); return c; $$'.

Comment: output that i am expecting is '{'

Comment: @MitchWheat inside a JavaScript store procedure, you only have access to JavaScript functions, not SQL function.

Comment: good point!.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the keyword `AS` in your stored procedure definition. You also need to define two parameters on the overloaded JavaScript function for substring. Finally, are you sure you want to use a stored procedure for this instead of a UDF or just SQL?

```
create or replace procedure
dsa ()
returns varchar
language javascript
as
$$
var b="{asdfasdf}"
var c=b.substring(0,1);
return c;
 $$;
 call dsa();
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to implement this functionality for other thing inside the store procedure